# Windows service not starting for non admin user

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-services

I have a exe of windows form application which is put in AppData folder of each logged in user. I have written a windows service which start exe after some time interval, but issue is it doesn't start/ stop when another non- admin user logs in. The service doesn't start the exe from that users App data folder. I tried using OnSesionChange event where I stopped/started service on Log-In/Off events.I have enabled required events like

```
        AutoLog = true;
        CanHandlePowerEvent = true;
        CanPauseAndContinue = true;
        CanHandleSessionChangeEvent = true;
        CanShutdown = true;
        CanStop = true;
```

But still service status is not shown in SCM .Even the non-Admin user is not able to start or stop service manually from SCM.  So how should I allow each logged in user to stop/start service. I read about SDDL but not getting how to use that.

Comment: Should the application run with user permissions or with admin permissions?

Answer (score 0):

In the windows service What is the `ServiceProcessInstaller`'s `Account` property set to??
Set it to `LocalSystem`. Set `serviceinstaller`'s `StartType` to `Automatic`. so that it gets started whenever the OS is started irrespective of the user who has logged into

Refer this if needed http://csharp-asp.blogspot.com/2008/10/how-to-create-simple-windows-service-in.html